# C: For-loop is executing despite ignoring initialization and increment expressions, therefore always true

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array

**CONTEXT:**

Hello, I'm trying to print a 7x6 Connect Four board where each section is `|___|` with three underscores. I want to create each center underscore an element of a 2D array so I can later update it.

**CONFLICT:**

I am getting no errors or warnings, but my output is just `|________ ...` with an infinite amount of underscores. I have successfully rewritten the code where three underscores are printed without assigning the center into an array (however obviously this code is useless for the sake of making an actual game since I can't update the center underscores). All the loop declarations in my current code were used in that successful variation, so I'm pretty sure those are not my issue. I can provide that code as well if you think it can help you. What I do know is that colCnt (column count) is incrementing forever and undCnt (underscore count) is stuck at 2. Because of this, I suspect that this for-loop is the primary issue in my code, however I do not know where:

```
                // Only print `_` three times as long as there have been 7 total or less vertical lines printed
                for (int undCnt = 0; undCnt < 3 && vertCnt <= 6; undCnt++)
                {

                    // Print left and right sections as `_`
                    if(undCnt != 1)
                    {
                        printf("_");

                        // If printing left section, increment column count
                        if(undCnt = 1){colCnt++;}
                    }

                    // Assign middle section to board array and prints it as `_`
                    else if(undCnt == 1)
                    {
                        arr[rowCnt][colCnt] = '_';
                        printf("%c", arr[rowCnt][colCnt]);

                    }

                }
```

**CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PrintBoard(char arr[6][7]);

int main()
{

    // Declaration of 7x6 2D board array: board[row][col]
    char board[6][7];

    PrintBoard(board);

    return 0;
}

void PrintBoard(char arr[6][7])
{
    int vertCnt = 0; // Counts vertical lines (8 per row, separates sections)
    int undCnt = 0; // Counts underscores (3 per section)
    int rowCnt = 0; // Counts rows (6 total)
    int colCnt = 0; // Count columns (7 total)

    // Print game title
    printf("      ~~ CONNECT FOUR ~~\n\n");

    for (int rowCnt = 0; rowCnt <= 6; rowCnt++)
        {
            // If current row is not the first, start it on a new line
            if (rowCnt > 0)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }

            // Creation of row: |___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
            for (int vertCnt = 0; vertCnt < 8; vertCnt++)
            {
                printf("|");

                // Only print `_` three times as long as there have been 7 total or less vertical lines printed
                for (int undCnt = 0; undCnt < 3 && vertCnt <= 6; undCnt++)
                {

                    // Print left and right sections as `_`
                    if(undCnt != 1)
                    {
                        printf("_");

                        // If printing left section, increment column count
                        if(undCnt = 1){colCnt++;}
                    }

                    // Assign middle section to board array and prints it as `_`
                    else if(undCnt == 1)
                    {
                        arr[rowCnt][colCnt] = '_';
                        printf("%c", arr[rowCnt][colCnt]);

                    }

                }
            }
        }

    // Print column numbers
    printf("\n  1   2   3   4   5   6   7\n\n");


    /* HOW THE BOARD SHOULD LOOK:

         ~~ CONNECT FOUR ~~             <--- GAME TITLE

    |___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
    |___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
    |___|___|___|___|___|___|___|       <--- BOARD
    |___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
    |___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
    |___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
      1   2   3   4   5   6   7         <--- COLUMN NUMBERS

    */

}
```

If you have any questions just let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Change `if(undCnt = 1)` to `if(undCnt == 1)`.  You're setting it to `1` each time that test is executed.

Comment: ...anyway you are making three tests on `undCnt` when only one is needed.

Comment: WHAT! I cannot believe this whole time I was assigning instead of comparing. It also did not occur to me how many times I did tests on `undCnt`. Thank you both!

Comment: Even if you fix that test, it will just be dead code, since you can only reach that point if `undCnt != 1`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered attempting to print "___|" all at once? Then all you have to do is check column count, if it is 0 print a '|' if it is the maximum column value add a newline character.

```
for(int row_count = 0; row_count<max_rows; rows++)
{
    for ( int column_count = 0; column_count<max_columns; columns++)
    {
         if( column_count==0)
         {
             printf('|');
         }
         printf("___|");        
    }
    printf('\n');
}
```

maybe something like this?